# How to publish an app privately on the App Store?

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store

I am making a small app with Flutter. I only want to let a few specific people who are iOS users download it. I know how to make a beta tester list on Google Play and only let certain emails access the app, but is there a similar way to do this on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TestFlight for this. It lets you specify who the "beta testers" should be, and takes care of distributing the app to them on demand.

Or, you can distribute the app Ad Hoc, yourself, direct to the few specific people; the app will be capable of running only on devices you have specified beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

The basic method of privately distributing an app is using what’s called Custom App distribution. This is done through either the App Business Manager or Apple School Manager. This depends obviously on the intended use of the app.

(Not sponsored ) you can follow this blog - https://blog.instabug.com/private-app-distribution-for-custom-ios-apps/